# Nginx SSL certificates not applying for websites

Tags: nginx

we are using nginx on ubuntu for serving ssl certificates for the custom domains linked up with our main website. Our code is generating all necassary ssl certificates, keys and files in specified folders according to nginx documentation. But when an custom domain website is opened the the ssl certificates are not applying to the websites .

This is the nginx status in the terminal

```
 nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
 enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-12-22 03:51:08 UTC; 4 days ago
 Docs: man:nginx(8)
 Process: 20065 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 -- 
 pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 20092 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; -s 
 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 20077 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; 
 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 20074 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process 
 on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 20080 (nginx)
 Tasks: 3
 Memory: 65.8M
 CPU: 6min 16.730s
 CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
       ├─20080 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process 
 on
       ├─20096 nginx: worker process
       └─20097 nginx: worker process

 Dec 22 03:51:08 qualzz.com systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and 
 a reverse proxy server.
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com systemd[1]: Reloading A high performance web server 
 and a reverse proxy server.
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "push.creaktor.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "push.creaktor.com" on [::]:80, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "app.ekikrat.in" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "notify.masterlywebsite.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "notify.masterlywebsite.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "app.qualzz.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com nginx[20092]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name 
 "admin.qualzz.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
 Dec 22 03:52:34 qualzz.com systemd[1]: Reloaded A high performance web server and 
 a reverse proxy server.
```

Nginx conf has this configuration

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript 
    text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }

    #mail {
    #       # See sample authentication script at:
    #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    #
    #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:110;
    #               protocol   pop3;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #
    #       server {
    #               listen     localhost:143;
    #               protocol   imap;
    #               proxy      on;
    #       }
    #}
```

And the conf files created for websites are

```
server { 
listen 80; listen [::]:80;  
root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; 
server_name app.floatcampaign.com;
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/html;
}
}
server { 
listen 443 ssl;
root /var/www/html; 
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; 
ssl_certificate     
/var/www/html/ssl/app.floatcampaign.com/app.floatcampaign.com.crt; 
ssl_certificate_key 
/var/www/html/ssl/app.floatcampaign.com/app.floatcampaign.com.key; 
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; 
server_name app.floatcampaign.com;
location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
 }
location /api {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
 }
location /images {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
 }
location //admin {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8085/;
 }
location /notifications {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
 }
location /notifications/api {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
 }
}
```

I am unable to find where the certificates are breaking to apply for websites

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`  and see what's issue

Comment: You need to start by removing all of those warnings. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and find where the duplicated `server` blocks are coming from.